# Azure cache error

Tags: caching, azure

i got this error on Windows azure cache and i really can;t figure it up:
It works just fine on emulator...

ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://KT.Cache:24233.

Any sugestions are wellcome..

Answer (score 1):

This is an irritatingly frequent problem and seems to point more to the failure of the service than any configuration problems. If you search for this error you will get a lot of possible solutions, not all of which work. I suggest:

1. Make sure that you are using the latest SDK. I am aware that there were changes (at least) between 2.0 and 2.1 in the caching libraries. Assume that the frequency of this error means that it is getting attention in the SDK.
2. Make the necessary adjustments to the MaxBufferSize. In some cases it fixes it quickly.
3. Catch the error and retry. It is not optimal, but stops things falling over completely. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17654499/3893)

Comment: I am getting this same error, but only in Azure (not locally on the emulator).  I am using in-role co-located caching on web roles. My question:  Do we only need to set `MaxBufferSize` in the `web.config` (in the `dataCacheClient` `transportProperties` section)?